# "to deserve the chair" meaning in the following conversation

Tags: idioms

[This is the sequence of the movie that I'm talking about.](https://www.filemail.com/d/xslttkrurrhkaxk)

The meaning of the last sentence is pretty obscure to me, I understand what "for some he deserves a medal" means, but I don't get what connection might be here between this sentence and "for some he deserves the chair", is it sarcastic?
I searched but found nothing.

The conversation :

> A (is a detective): You're CIA.
> I met plenty like you in the Green Zone.
> So why are you worried about me?

> B: Because of the man you're chasing.
> He's dangerous.

> A: Heh, he saved my life.
> What was that, an accident?

> B: Yeah. I was his best friend.

> A: Then why do you want him so bad?

> B: Because he used to kill people
> for his country. Now he just kills them.
> His victims.
> The ones that we know of.
> **For some he deserves a medal,
> for some the chair.**

Comment: I don't think that link is what you meant to link.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks for saying, I updated the link.

Comment: Thanks!  It would also help to include the text in the question so that people don't have to download a file (especially since that link can't be watched online and expires in a week).  We want questions to remain useful indefinitely.

Comment: Why don't you give the movie title and year? You are not being very helpful.

Comment: 'The chair' is almost certainly 'the electric chair' (an American method of execution). Some people think that someone deserves a medal; others think that he deserves to be put to death in prison.

Comment: "electric chair" makes sense, Thanks. @MichaelHarvey The movie is a long serial I don't think it's helpful to name.

Comment: I [found it](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/825429) - _Person of Interest_ (2011) but @user48 should have told us that.

Comment: @user48 -  It is very important to name the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted dialogue is from an American film, *Person of Interest* (2011)

The chair' is almost certainly 'the electric chair' (an American method of execution). Some people, it is being said, think that a person being discussed deserves a medal; others think that he deserves to be put to death in prison.